# Checking if a user has liked a page or not without user_likes permission

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Currently, I am creating a function to check if a user has liked specific page on Facebook, and reward them with something in return if they have liked the page. During development, I tested the function out, and it works as intended.

However, I did not notice that to use the user_likes permissions, we will need to do a App Review, and we can only use the permission if we have passed the review. In Facebook's policies, they have stated that they do not allow the permissions if we use it just to check if a user has liked a page or not.

Is there any alternative ways to go around this and to get the information without the permissions? Or should I just scrap the whole function? Would like some advice on this. Thank you.

Comment: No there is no way

Comment: _“Or should I just scrap the whole function?”_ - of course you should, because apart from the permission issue, you are not even allowed to reward users for liking stuff. https://developers.facebook.com/policy, 4.5: _“Only incentivize a person to log into your app, enter a promotion on your app’s Page, check-in at a place, or to use Messenger to communicate with your business. Don’t incentivize other actions.”_

Comment: I see. I guess if its against the policy, theres no other way than to simply scrap it off.